# Compiling SCSS to CSS Compile error due to PHP Variables in SCSS file. How to get past it?

Tags: sass, osclass

I have a bunch of SCSS file and I am trying to compile them to CSS. I have tried using both [Koala](http://koala-app.com/) and [Scout](http://mhs.github.io/scout-app/).

```
Error:
C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\officeincambridge\public_html\oc-content\themes\bender\sass\user.scss
error sass/user.scss (Line 2: Undefined variable: "$widgetbackground".)
create css/user.css
```

.SCSS file:

```
.user-card{
background-color:$widgetbackground;
position: relative;
padding-left:120px;
height:120px;
@include border-radius(4px);
margin-bottom:25px;
ul{
    padding:15px;
    margin:0;
    list-style: none;
}
```

I understand why the error is coming up, but how can I compile the SCSS file with PHP variables? For further info, I am using [OSCLASS](http://osclass.org/)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Sass is a Ruby tool, not PHP.

Edit: according the source code, `$widgetbackground` is defined in the `colors.scss` file.

Comment: It's there any other way I can do it? It says [HERE](http://doc.osclass.org/How_to_modify_Bender_theme) that I should be able to compile the files?

Comment: So I've looked in the colors.scss and you are correct. `$widgetbackground: #f7f7f7;`, does that mean I would have to manually replace all files using $widgetbackground to use #f7f7f7?

Comment: No, you have to import the `colors.scss` file (`@import "colors.scss";`) like in `main.scss`.

Comment: Note: this theme does not use Sass correctly. Perhaps because of the Grunt task? (that I does not find in the project)

Comment: I see! This gets past the error but now I get another error ` error sass/user.scss (Line 7: Undefined mixin 'border-radius'.)
identical css/user.css `, so how can I deal with @include (do I need to import another file?). 

Regarding your last reply, that's fine about not using SASS correctly, its just the CSS file is minified/compressed to a single line making it tedious to use. As long as I can generate CSS files thats fine

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed compile SCSS with PHP, please go through the following [Module](http://leafo.net/scssphp/) . I've used that in my project, and it works just fine. All you have to do is,

1. Include the Module into your project
2. Create a Style.php file. and specify the input directory, given in their document.
3. Pass the scss file you have under your assets directory, as an argument to style.php

   `style.php/?p=application.scss`
4. You will have the compiled file generated, under your Assets Directory,

Style.php File

```
    $scss = new scssc();
    $scss->setFormatter("scss_formatter_compressed");

    $server = new scss_server("assets/", "assets/", $scss);
    $server->serve();
```

Here "Assets" means the directory which contain the SCSS files, be sure about the relative path.

Sass is a great tool, happy coding. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am no longer working on the project above but I will be sure to check this out when I next come across it!